# css3 : how to put height 100% on a static/relative (no absolute positionned) div?

Tags: css

I have a container and 2 divs inside: 
1 header (whose height should be free if I add some lines) and an userList.
I want the userList to have the height of the container : any idea how ?
(no JS solution, better if no position: asbolute used)

```css
#container {
 width: 300px;
 height:400px;
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
#header{
 background-color: #FFF500;
}
#userList {
 background-color: #00FF00;
 width:290px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="header">line1<br>line2<br>line3</div>
    <div id="userList">
     line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>
        line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your example is working? the `userList` element has the same height as the `container` element. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: If you want an element to have 100% height of the window then you could use height:100vh;

Comment: the problem is: userlist overlaps its container : look at the green and red divs !

Comment: Alright, I think you're trying to help us find a solution for the solution you think you've found for your problem instead of the problem, what is the scenario you want to create exactly? example: *I would like my header and container to both be contained within the same space, not overflowing the container but I don't know their height*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your `.userList` have the same height as his container, but with the yellow box it goes down. The best solution with your requirements is as this:

Your requirements:

> no JS solution, better if no position: asbolute used)

```css
#container {
 width: 300px;
 height:400px;
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
#header{
    width: 300px;
 background-color: #FFF500;
}
#userList {
 background-color: #00FF00;
 width:290px;
 height: 100%;
 overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">line1<br>line2<br>line3</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="userList">
    line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>
    line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

The only I need is take out the `#header` division and give it the same with as `#container`. By this mode, `#container` and `#userList` have got the same height.

Comment: This solution requires modification of markup. OP may not be able to, or want to, change html.

Comment: Hi @Chris where do you read `OP may not be able to, or want to, change html`  in OP's question? I put the requirements in my answer: `no JS solution, better if no position: asbolute used)`. This answer fits with the requirements of OP. Your answer is good too, but mine that's not neccesary bad answer, it's simply different technique. However, I want and I like flexbox, but I wish better behaviour and better compatibility. What about this?

Comment: I didn't say it was a bad answer. However, i think it's a better practice not to change the html, if possible. A css-only solution is more flexible, and may be more applicable and helpful to future readers of this question (some of which might not be able to change markup).

Answer (score 0):

One good way of doing this is with `display: flex` and `flex-direction` properties.

This way, you can have a `header` with flexible height, and a `userlist` that is always contained within the `container`. This way, you also don't have to change your markup and move the `header` outside your `container`.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/5a6e68se/)

Full code:

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height:400px;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#header{
  background-color: #FFF500;
}
#userList {
  background-color: #00FF00;
  width:290px;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">line1<br>line2<br>line3</div>
  <div id="userList">
     line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>
        line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>line<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I think it achieves OPs' desired behaviour perfectly. Please comment if you're downvoting.

Comment: not sure why would anyone downvote this, it's the right solution.

Comment: I don't know, but say `The right way of doing this is with flexbox` maybe have the culprit. You can't evangelize with your only vision of truth. Note that I love flexbox and understand your solution as a good solution.

Comment: heh, that wasn't my intention. I modified my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Hahaha, sorry if I disturb you. Nice to meet you :)